# Why does BaKoMa sometimes keep working on LaTeX MS despite errors, and sometimes stop?

Tags: errors, bakoma

BaKoMa is my favorite WYSIWYG LaTeX editing software. Sometimes it keeps running despite errors in the .tex manuscript.  Sometimes it quits---there is not "r" code. Why does it run sometimes and why quit other times? I wish it would keep running all the time

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you mean that the editor quits? Or do you mean that compilation ends with errors? Also, I don't know what you mean by '"r" code'. In general, if you run TeX compilation with appropriate options, it will try to keep going despite errors if it can. However, there are some errors which mean it isn't possible to complete the compilation and, in that case, compilation will necessarily stop no matter what options you've passed. It is difficult to say anything further without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), however, since there are many different errors!

Answer (score 6):

BaKoMa TeX runs TeX in scroll mode (is equivalent of 'r' option).

Compilation is stopped only in fatal cases (more then 100 errors in one paragraph).